# blackberry webworks: crash when loading local page into iframe

Tags: javascript, blackberry, iframe, blackberry-webworks

in a blackberry webworks application i try to load a page into an iframe that is packaged with the app, but the app keeps crashing (it opens the splash screen and doesnt load anything)
The page i want to load is located at (relative to the index.html of my app):

```
./pages/help_en/home.html
```

and i tried to load it with this paths:

```
pages/help_en/home.html
./pages/help_en/home.html
local:///pages/help_en/home.html
```

but all of them lead to that crash.
When i load it from an external server, it works fine...
Maybe i should also mention, that it only happens on Smartphones, on PlayBook (Tablet) it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The below code sample should work to load a local page (within the app) into an iframe. It also uses the same folder structure as yours. It has been tested and packaged into a WebWorks app and loaded onto a device and the page loads properly in the iframe. Along with a main page, ensure that you also include a config.xml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Iframe</title>
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" 
        content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=no,target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeSrc(){
        document.getElementById('theFrame').src = "pages/help_en/home.html";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Iframe is below<br/>
    <button onclick="changeSrc()">click me</button><br/>
    <iframe id="theFrame" src=""></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats how i tried it... as soon as i click the button, the app crashed. i bypassed that issue by loading the contents directly into the page without an iframe...